# Gnus: How to archive emails according to the account they were written from? [gcc-self not working as expected]

Tags: emacs, gnus

I have two mail accounts, `foo.bar@uni.edu` and `foo.bar@gmail.com`. I would like to archive messages I send from either one in a corresponding "sent mail" folder (`nnimap+foo.bar@uni.edu:Sent Items` and `foo.bar@gmail.com:[Google Mail]/Sent Mail`).

I tried to set

```
(setq gnus-message-archive-group
  '(("uni" "nnimap+foo.bar@uni.edu:Sent Items")
    ("gmail" "nnimap+foo.bar@gmail.com:[Google Mail]/Sent Mail")
    ))
```

but that does not set Gcc (new messages don't have a Gcc; any solution here?). I thus went back to `(setq
gnus-message-archive-group "nnimap+foo.bar@uni.edu:Sent Items")` which sets Gcc
correctly (for the main account `foo.bar@uni.edu`) if I open a new message in *Group* via `m`.

I then tried to use `gcc-self` via `gnus-parameters` to archive the sent mails correctly:

```
(setq gnus-parameters
       `((,(rx "nnimap+foo.bar@uni.edu")
         (gcc-self . "nnimap+foo.bar@uni.edu:Sent Items"))
         (,(rx "nnimap+foo.bar@gmail.com")
         (gcc-self . "foo.bar@gmail.com:[Google Mail]/Sent Mail"))))
```

The manual (http://www.gnus.org/manual/gnus_28.html) says that if `gcc-self` is
a string, it is simply inserted literally as Gcc header. I made the following
experience: Wherever I start a new message in *Group* via `C-u m` (with `m`, Gcc
is "nnimap+foo.bar@uni.edu:Sent Items" as mentioned before), Gcc is taken to be
the name the point was on in *Group* before `m` was hit. So if the point is on
`nnimap+foo.bar@gmail.com:Drafts`, Gcc will be `Gcc:
nnimap+foo.bar@gmail.com:Drafts` (instead of `foo.bar@gmail.com:[Google
Mail]/Sent Mail`). How can this be fixed and messages archived in the corresponding sent mail folders if written via `C-u m`? In other words, why are the `Gcc`'s not set correctly?

[this is on Emacs 24.3.50.1, Gnus v5.13]

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same issue as you. Even though I was adding in a gcc-self parameter to be "INBOX.Sent" when I sent the message it was ending up in "nnfolder+archive:sent.YYYY-MM"

My setup is that I have a default account (home) and a secondary account (work) both imap (but not Gmail, hopefully this answer still applies)

Through a lot of trial and error I managed to get it functioning as I wanted: work emails to be saved in the work sent folder, home emails to be saved in the home sent folder.

In the gnus-parameters I simply changed my `gcc-self` param to gcc and it worked! However, only for the secondary address.

For the default address I set `gnus-message-archive-group`

A cut down of my ~/.gnus file

```
(setq gnus-select-method
      '(nnimap "home"
                (nnimap-address "mail.homeaddress.com")
                (nnimap-server-port 143)
                (nnimap-stream starttls)
                (nnimap-inbox "INBOX")
                 ))

(setq gnus-secondary-select-methods
      '((nnimap "work"
                (nnimap-address "mail.workaddress.com")
                (nnimap-server-port 143)
                (nnimap-stream starttls)
                (nnimap-inbox "INBOX"))))
(setq gnus-parameters
      '(
        ("work"
         (posting-style
          (address "me@workaddress.com")
          (gcc "nnimap+work:INBOX.Sent")))))

(setq gnus-message-archive-group "nnimap:INBOX.Sent")
```

Notice that I don't have any `posting-styles` for home.

I hope this helps.

Emacs Version 24.3.1, Gnus v5.13

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem during my Gnus setup. I use Gmail for personal stuff and Outlook for work. My goal is to compose/reply messages using the corresponding account that I am currently working on in Gnus. Based on the suggestions from [robsearles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1308653/robsearles), I managed to achieve this goal using `gnus-posting-styles`. Here is the sample code I use.

```
;; Archive outgoing email in Sent folder on imap.gmail.com
(setq gnus-message-archive-method '(nnimap "imap.gmail.com")
      gnus-message-archive-group "[Gmail]/Sent Mail")

;; Set return email address based on incoming email address
(setq gnus-posting-styles
      `((".*"
        (address "foo.bar@gmail.com")
        (name "Foo Bar")
        ("X-Message-SMTP-Method" "smtp smtp.gmail.com 587 foo.bar@gmail.com")
       )
       ("^nnimap[+]outlook:.*"
       (address "foo.bar@outlook.com")
       (name "Foo Bar")
       ("X-Message-SMTP-Method" "smtp smtp-mail.outlook.com 587 foo.bar@outlook.com")
       (gcc "\"nnimap+outlook:Sent Items\"")
       )
      )
    )
```

The `gnus-message-archive-method` and `gnus-message-archive-group` set the default archiving behavior which archives messages to my Gmail `Sent` folder. The `gcc` tag in `gnus-posting-styles` instructs Gnus to archive messages to my Outlook `Sent` folder when I am working with the Outlook account. I also get the benefit of automatically selecting the outgoing mail server depending on the email account I am working on with the `X-message-SMTP-Method` tag. Outlook seems to automatically archives a message to the `Sent` folder whenever it is sent, so I used `(gcc nil)` in my actual setup to avoid duplicates. You can of course change outlook to whatever mail service you are using.